# List of Facebook fields returned by Social Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Does anybody know if there is an authoritative list of fields that can be returned by the Facebook Social Graph API? For example the fields returned by an Author object are different to a Company object. Is there a list of all the possible fields and the data types?

Answer (score 32):

There is a tool called graph API explorer.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

you can search for field names by typing on[image] "search for a field" on the left side

Comment: Nowadays, they only show a few fields in the explorer :'(

Comment: Has this feature been removed? I don't get a field list.

Comment: They removed this now. Sad.

Comment: The feature is still there as of 1-jan-2017

Answer (score 23):

If you want to discover all field available to return on an endpoint  Simply add metadata=1 to your query... Like https://graph.facebook.com/me?metadata=1&acccess_token="PUT A VALID ACCESS TOKEN"

Answer (score 20):

As the question is to list the fields for quick use and not only show how;

This is the list of fields (53) retrieved by Facebook Graph API Explorer to date, using default permission access token for a facebook app (web canvas) as a json Format:

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "id",
        "description": "The id of this person's user account. This ID is unique to each app and cannot be used across different apps. [Our upgrade guide provides more information about app-specific IDs](/docs/apps/upgrading/#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids)",
        "type": "numeric string"
      },
      {
        "name": "about",
        "description": "Equivalent to the `bio` field",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "admin_notes",
        "description": "Notes added by viewing page on this person",
        "type": "list<pageadminnote>"
      },
      {
        "name": "age_range",
        "description": "The age segment for this person expressed as a minimum and maximum age. For example, more than 18, less than 21.",
        "type": "agerange"
      },
      {
        "name": "birthday",
        "description": "The person's birthday.  This is a fixed format string, like `MM/DD/YYYY`.  However, people can control who can see the year they were born separately from the month and day so this string can be only the year (YYYY) or the month + day (MM/DD)",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "context",
        "description": "Social context for this person",
        "type": "usercontext"
      },
      {
        "name": "cover",
        "description": "The person's cover photo",
        "type": "coverphoto"
      },
      {
        "name": "currency",
        "description": "The person's local currency information",
        "type": "currency"
      },
      {
        "name": "devices",
        "description": "The list of devices the person is using. This will return only iOS and Android devices",
        "type": "list<userdevice>"
      },
      {
        "name": "education",
        "description": "The person's education",
        "type": "list<educationexperience>"
      },
      {
        "name": "email",
        "description": "The person's primary email address listed on their profile. This field will not be returned if no valid email address is available",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "employee_number",
        "description": "The person's employee number, as set by the company via SCIM API",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "favorite_athletes",
        "description": "Athletes the person likes",
        "type": "list<experience>"
      },
      {
        "name": "favorite_teams",
        "description": "Sports teams the person likes",
        "type": "list<experience>"
      },
      {
        "name": "first_name",
        "description": "The person's first name",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "gender",
        "description": "The gender selected by this person, `male` or `female`. This value will be omitted if the gender is set to a custom value",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "hometown",
        "description": "The person's hometown",
        "type": "page"
      },
      {
        "name": "inspirational_people",
        "description": "The person's inspirational people",
        "type": "list<experience>"
      },
      {
        "name": "install_type",
        "description": "Install type",
        "type": "enum"
      },
      {
        "name": "installed",
        "description": "Is the app making the request installed?",
        "type": "bool"
      },
      {
        "name": "interested_in",
        "description": "Genders the person is interested in",
        "type": "list<string>"
      },
      {
        "name": "is_shared_login",
        "description": "Is this a shared login (e.g. a gray user)",
        "type": "bool"
      },
      {
        "name": "is_verified",
        "description": "People with large numbers of followers can have the authenticity of their identity [manually verified by Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/196050490547892). This field indicates whether the person's profile is verified in this way. This is distinct from the `verified` field",
        "type": "bool"
      },
      {
        "name": "labels",
        "description": "Labels applied by viewing page on this person",
        "type": "list<pagelabel>"
      },
      {
        "name": "languages",
        "description": "Facebook Pages representing the languages this person knows",
        "type": "list<experience>"
      },
      {
        "name": "last_name",
        "description": "The person's last name",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "link",
        "description": "A link to the person's Timeline",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "locale",
        "description": "The person's locale",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "location",
        "description": "The person's current location as entered by them on their profile. This field is not related to check-ins",
        "type": "page"
      },
      {
        "name": "meeting_for",
        "description": "What the person is interested in meeting for",
        "type": "list<string>"
      },
      {
        "name": "middle_name",
        "description": "The person's middle name",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "name",
        "description": "The person's full name",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "name_format",
        "description": "The person's name formatted to correctly handle Chinese, Japanese, or Korean ordering",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "payment_pricepoints",
        "description": "The person's payment pricepoints",
        "type": "paymentpricepoints"
      },
      {
        "name": "political",
        "description": "The person's political views",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "public_key",
        "description": "The person's PGP public key",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "quotes",
        "description": "The person's favorite quotes",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "relationship_status",
        "description": "The person's relationship status",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "religion",
        "description": "The person's religion",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "security_settings",
        "description": "Security settings",
        "type": "securitysettings"
      },
      {
        "name": "shared_login_upgrade_required_by",
        "description": "The time that the shared loginneeds to be upgraded to Business Manager by",
        "type": "datetime"
      },
      {
        "name": "significant_other",
        "description": "The person's significant other",
        "type": "user"
      },
      {
        "name": "sports",
        "description": "Sports played by the person",
        "type": "list<experience>"
      },
      {
        "name": "test_group",
        "description": "Platform test group",
        "type": "unsigned int32"
      },
      {
        "name": "third_party_id",
        "description": "A string containing an anonymous, but unique identifier for the person. You can use this identifier with third parties",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "timezone",
        "description": "The person's current timezone offset from UTC",
        "type": "float (min: -24) (max: 24)"
      },
      {
        "name": "token_for_business",
        "description": "A token that is the same across a business's apps. Access to this token requires that the person be logged into your app or have a role on your app. This token will change if the business owning the app changes",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "updated_time",
        "description": "Updated time",
        "type": "datetime"
      },
      {
        "name": "verified",
        "description": "Indicates whether the account has been verified. This is distinct from the `is_verified` field. Someone is considered verified if they take any of the following actions:",
        "type": "bool"
      },
      {
        "name": "video_upload_limits",
        "description": "Video upload limits",
        "type": "videouploadlimits"
      },
      {
        "name": "viewer_can_send_gift",
        "description": "Can the viewer send a gift to this person?",
        "type": "bool"
      },
      {
        "name": "website",
        "description": "The person's website",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "work",
        "description": "Details of a person`s work experience",
        "type": "list<workexperience>"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can use an online tool to export to CSV for easy reference.

http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb57f9b6

And for how to retrieve the list ? Please refer to the other answers in this post

Answer (score 2):

Here is the list of them from the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions)

Here are the most common public_user fields:

```
id
cover
name
first_name
last_name
age_range
link
gender
locale
picture
timezone
updated_time
verified
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the official Social Graph API documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Look under the section "Objects"

Comment: Thanks - the official docs don't give the exact data types of fields being returned though such as max length of strings.

Comment: Arg, the Graph documentation is the worst one i ever seen.

Comment: I m also have same issue

Comment: Now they have improved the docs - see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user